# In hive, querying is faster for which table(external or internal)? and why?

Tags: hql, hive

I want to know, querying is faster for which table(external or internal) in hive? and why?

Answer (score 3):

There is no speed difference between external table and internal table.

The main difference is that you can specify store location in external table while internal table store data in his own way.

Comment: That first part is true. That second part I'm not sure about. The external keyword specifies where the data is located and keeps it there. If you don't specify `EXTERNAL` the data will be moved from it's current location to Hive's standard location.

Comment: The `EXTERNAL` keyword lets you create a table and provide a `LOCATION` so that Hive does not use a default location for this table. This comes in handy if you already have data generated. When dropping an `EXTERNAL` table, data in the table is **NOT** deleted from the file system.